# TFS 2015: Removing WSS 3.0

Tags: tfs-2015

I was in the process of doing an in-place OS upgrade (2008 > 2012) on the TFS server and it failed during setup with the following error in the compatibility report:

*Windows won't install unless each of these things is taken care of.  Close Windows Setup, take care of teach one, and then restart Windows Setup to continue. 
                   Make these changes: 
                   Turn off these Windows features:
                        Windows SharePoint Services 3.0 - Please read Microsoft Knowledge Base
                        article: 962216*

So based on the KB it looks like we need to update WSS 3.0 to SP2.  Since we aren't using any SharePoint sites with TFS, is it OK to just remove WSS 3.0 from Add/Remove programs?

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/962216/you-cannot-upgrade-windows-server-2008-to-windows-server-2008-r2-or-to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, yes. You can check "SharePoint Web Application" section in Administration console:

[image]

If there are no configured applications, you can remove WSS 3.0.

Comment: Thanks Shamrai.   Under SharePoint Web Applications, it is empty for me.  I will try uninstalling WSS 3.0 later this week.